# widget resize when keyboard appear

Tags: flutter, dart

when I show keyboard, the widget look shorter

[image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xFFF8F8F8),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex:8,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text('data');
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 8,
                        child: TextField(
                          cursorColor: Colors.white,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            isDense: true,
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xFFE2E4E8),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Color(0xFFE2E4E8))
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Color(0xFFE2E4E8))
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Color(0xFFE2E4E8))
                            ),
                            prefixIcon: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('123');
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.sentiment_satisfied_alt,
                                color: Colors.pink,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                            labelText: '',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Center(
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: Material(
                              color: Colors.transparent, // Button color
                              child: InkWell(
                                splashColor: Colors.red, // Splash color
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Icon(Icons.send, color: Color(0xFFCC306F)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` on Scaffold. default, it is true.

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Comment: the code is not working

Comment: what do you after using this? make sure have body scrollable.